# Sql check range exist between a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table like

```
----------------------------------
|  ID  |  MinValue  |  MaxValue  |
----------------------------------
|  1   |      0     |    10      |
|  2   |     11     |    20      |
|  3   |     21     |    30      |
```

and i have a range value for example

```
minV = 5 
maxV = 15
```

i want to get row who's value matchs the range from database table

**Example**
 minV = 5 ,
    maxV = 15 should return first and second record

**Example**
 minV = 5 ,
    maxV = 35 should return all record

**Example**
 minV = 5 ,
    maxV = 9 should return first record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where @minv <= t.maxvalue and
      @maxv >= t.minvalue
```

This is the logic for overlapping intervals -- basically, each "min" is less than the other's "max".